# Invalid viewstate error when posting back to same page

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, server.transfer

I'm having some issues with an *Invalid Viewstate* error and I can understand why it's happening but I don't know how to fix it.

I have a page which is similar to this `/story/?id=123` but I'm using a different page to `Server.Transfer` to this page.

So I've set up `/info` to `Server.TransferRequest("/story/?id=123")` and it works fine until the page does a postback to itself.

We have a login form on this page which simply reloads the page but when it does it seems to add `/?id=123` onto the end of the URL so it ends up like this `/info/?id=123` thus causing an *Invalid Viewstate* error.

I've already tried adding `EnableViewStateMac="false"` - this fixes the error but it doesn't log the user in as expected so it does not give the required result.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to redirect to my page other than `Server.TransferRequest` but still keeping the nice URL? - I don't want to `Response.Redirect` if I can avoid it.
2. If not, is there an easy way to fix this error that doesn't require me adding `EnableViewStateMac="false"`?

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37753/Access-ViewState-Across-Pages

Comment: @BeemerGuy.net Thanks for the comment - I've just tried to implement this but can't get it work - The article is for two separate pages and not a single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316920

I believe that article will explain why you are having the problem and it gives a solution to fix it.

I know you don't want to use Response.Redirect, but I think that would also solve the problem.

> ## PRB: "View State Is Invalid" Error Message When You Use Server.Transfer
>
> This article was previously published under Q316920
>
> ### Retired KB Content Disclaimer
>
> This article was written about products for which Microsoft no longer
>   offers support. Therefore, this article is offered "as is" and will no
>   longer be updated.
>
> ### SYMPTOMS
>
> When you use `HttpServerUtility.Transfer("page name", true)`, you
>   receive the following error message:
>
> > The View State is invalid for this page and might be corrupted
>
> ### CAUSE
>
> This problem occurs because the `EnableViewStateMac` attribute of the
>   `<pages>` element is set to `true` by default. When this attribute is
>   set to true, ASP.NET runs a message authentication check (MAC) on the
>   view state of the page when the page is posted back from the client.
>   This check determines if the view state of the page was modified on
>   the client. For security purposes, it is recommended that you keep
>   this attribute set to `true`.
>
> When you call the `Server.Transfer` method and set the second
>   parameter to `true`, you preserve the `QueryString` and the `Form`
>   collections. One of the form fields is the hidden __VIEWSTATE form
>   field, which holds the view state for the page. The view state message
>   authentication check fails because the message authentication check
>   only checks each page. Therefore, the view state from the page that
>   calls `Server.Transfer` is not valid on the destination page.
>
> View state is page scoped and is valid for that page only. View state
>   should not be transferred across pages.
>
> ### RESOLUTION
>
> To resolve this problem, use one of the following methods.
>
> #### Resolution 1
>
> Transfer values between pages to pass your server control values to
>   the other pages. For more information, refer to the following MSDN
>   documentation:   [Passing Server Control Values Between
>   Pages](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(vs.71).aspx) 
>   This requires that you create public properties for each property of a
>   control that you want to access from the destination page.
>
> If you have many controls, and if you want to access the properties of
>   these controls from another page, you can also declare those controls
>   as public variables. For example:
>
> **Page1.aspx**
>
> ```
> Public Class Page1
>     Public WithEvents TextBox1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
>
>     'Insert your code here.
> End Class
> ```
>
> **Page2.aspx**
>
> ```
> Dim sourcePage As Page1
> sourcePage = CType(Context.Handler, WebForm1)
> Response.Write(sourcePage.TextBox1.Text)
> ```
>
> #### Resolution 2
>
> Do not pass the second parameter (which is `false` by default) when
>   you call `Server.Transfer`. For example:
>
> ```
> Server.Transfer("<page name>")
> ```
>
> This code does not send the `QueryString` and the `Form` fields to the
>   page that is called. When no data is transferred, ASP.NET does not run
>   the message authentication check.
>
> ### MORE INFORMATION
>
> #### Steps to Reproduce the Behavior
>
> 1. Create an .aspx page named WebForm1.aspx that transfers execution to another page. Add the following code to WebForm1.aspx:
>
>    ```
>    <%@ Page language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
>
>    <html>  
>      <body>  
>        <form id="WebForm1" method="post" runat="server">
>          <asp:TextBox id="txtName" runat="server">Your Name</asp:TextBox><br>
>          <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
>        </form>   
>      </body>
>    </html>
>
>    <script runat=server>
>    Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
>      Server.Transfer("WebForm2.aspx",true)
>    End Sub
>
>    </script>
>    ```
> 2. Create another .aspx page named WebForm2.aspx, and then add the following code:
>
>    ```
>    <%@ Page language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
>
>    <html>
>      <body>  
>        <form id="WebForm2" method="post" runat="server">
>          <asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server" >Web Form 2</asp:Label>
>        </form>
>
>      </body>
>    </html>
>
>    <script runat=server>
>    Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
>
>    Dim thisPage As System.Web.UI.Page
>    Dim nameTextBox As TextBox
>
>      thisPage = CType(Context.Handler, System.Web.UI.Page)
>      nameTextBox =  CType(thisPage.FindControl("txtName"), System.Web.UI.Control)
>
>      lblName.Text = "Your name is '" & nameTextBox.Text & "'."   
>
>    End Sub
>
>    </script>
>    ```
> 3. Open WebForm1.aspx in your browser, and then click **Submit**.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I saw that earlier and unfortunately couldn't use any of the solutions - maybe I'll just have to use a Response.Redirect after all.